# How to show status of huge process to client(web)

Tags: asp.net

Environment : ASP.NET, C#

I am writing a web program that will export 12 tables to another database. When the user click the "Export" button, the export process will get started. The thing is, I like to show some messages to client such as "preparing..., deleting old records..., exporting..., export completed."

But now, It is showing all status once 12 table are completed.

Please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Doing long processes like this is on a web page is probably not a good idea, you will need change the timeout settings on pages etc

Rather build a windows service that does all the work. You can then use the Page to initialte the process. The service could update some status that is read by the page. This way the page does very little work, ie initiate the process and poll for status updates. This can be done via simple jquery/ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

try this

put this on  c#
and call ajavascript function per process

Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("1","alert('add to table now')");

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript timer to periodically load content from a status page or service.

The timer is fairly simple:

```
setTimeout('checkProcessStatus()', waitTime);
```

The update itself depends on your choice of tech - for instance if using MVC and jQuery:

```
function checkProcessStatus() {
    //dynamically add the html from the status page to <div id="taskStatusPanel"
    $('#taskStatusPanel').load('export/status/' + taskId);

    //set timer to call this again
    setTimeout('checkProcessStatus()', waitTime);
}
```

Then the `ExportController.Status` action would return a simple view that displayed the HTML for the current status.